# Chrome Extension Alarms Create 'undefined'

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension

I'm creating a plugin for google chrome extensions and for the life of me cannot figure out this error.

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'create' of undefined(anonymous function)
```

The strange thing is the alarm works fine! My manifest has the proper permissions:

```
  "permissions": ["activeTab","storage","alarms"]
```

And my code in background.js which corresponds to the error looks like so:

```
var alarmName = "test";

chrome.alarms.create(alarmName, {
  delayInMinutes: 0,
  periodInMinutes: 1
});

chrome.alarms.onAlarm.addListener(function(alarmName) {
  alert("Here");
});
```

Any ideas why I'm getting this issue? Thanks

EDIT: Here's my whole manifest.

```
{
"manifest_version": 2,

"name": "Test App",
"options_page": "options.html",
"description": "Amazing new test app!",
"version": "1.0",

"icons": { "16": "icon16.png",
       "48": "icon48.png",
      "128": "icon128.png" },

"browser_action": {
"default_icon": "icon.png",
"default_popup": "popup.html"
},

"content_scripts": [ {
"js": [ "jquery.min.js", "jquery.js", "background.js" ],
"matches": [ "http://*/*", "https://*/*"]
}],
"background": {
"scripts": ["jquery.min.js", "jquery.js", "background.js"],
"persistent":true
},
"web_accessible_resources": ["src/options/options.html"],
"permissions": [
"activeTab","storage","alarms"]
}
```

Comment: what is `chrome.alarms`? This is undefined for me. Therefore the `create` property doesn't exist, which explains your error message

Comment: It's chrome's api to schedule tasks. https://developer.chrome.com/apps/alarms

Comment: Could you post your manifest?  I doubt that's your problem, but we might as well make sure.

Comment: Sure, just uploaded it. Thanks, hopefully it's a simple fix!

Comment: In addition to the answer, there's also no reason to include jquery.min and jquery.  Just pick one.

Comment: Good point. Thank you. Looks like I have a little word to do to clean this up...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
"content_scripts": [ {
  "js": [ "jquery.min.js", "jquery.js", "background.js" ],
  "matches": [ "http://*/*", "https://*/*"]
}],
```

First, a piece of advice.

### Never call your content scripts background.js

This is a huge source of confusion, since it's not the same as background scripts.

And it's also the reason it does not work: [content scripts don't have access to most Chrome APIs](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/content_scripts):

> However, content scripts have some limitations. They cannot:
>
> Use chrome.* APIs, with the exception of:
>
> - extension ( getURL , inIncognitoContext , lastError , onRequest , sendRequest )
> - i18n
> - runtime ( connect , getManifest , getURL , id , onConnect , onMessage , sendMessage )
> - storage

You'll need to message your (real) background script to do this for you. **Don't reuse code like that, since it's a completely different context.**

The alarm "works fine" since you also have this code in the background page, where it works properly.

You can observe this by opening `chrome://extensions` and clicking the "background page" link to inspect it. You seem to be looking in the current page's console and seeing the content script's output.

Take a moment to read the [Architecture Overview](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/overview#arch).

Comment: Wow thanks Xan. I had no idea. I'll take the time to familiarize myself with the architecture. So I understand the contentscript will be everything interacting with the current tab, and the background script is only needed for one instance of a long running script?

Comment: Basically, yes. Also, because the content script code is interacting with the page directly, it's a "less secure" context and most APIs are disabled. High-privilege tasks should be done in the background script, _usually_ with [Messaging](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/messaging) as a "glue" between them.

Comment: Ahh I see. Ok so keep all my page interaction inside of the content script, and keep the alarms and any other high privileged tasks inside background.js. Think I got it! Thanks for your help!